# Convert myType to Int

Tags: haskell, casting, converters

I have my type, which defined here:
`data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat  deriving Show`

I want to defined function, that convert Nat to Int.
Help please

all my attempts are like this:

```
toInt :: Nat -> Int
toInt n = show n :: Int
```

and give not result

Comment: `show` has type `Show a => a -> String`, so `show n :: Int` will give a type error.

Comment: I think your attempt suggests you don't have any idea what the code is supposed to do. You may want to start over from the problem description and think about what it means.

Comment: OK, how about something like this: `toInt x = case length (show x) of {4 -> 1; 9 -> 2; n -> (div n 7) + 1}; toInt :: Nat -> Int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from

```
toInt Zero     = ??? -- this one is really easy
toInt (Succ n) = ??? (toInt n) -- not much harder
```

Comment: You give a bit too much away, I think.

Comment: @user3625577, it's a blank for you to fill in.